# Setting a random color embed | Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to set a random color with Discord.js but it keeps throwing me errors. I have tried serveral methods on other posts as well, but it couldn't fix the problem

The code:

```
const Command = require("../structures/Command.js");
const config = require("../data/config.json");
const {MessageEmbed} = require('discord.js')

module.exports = new Command({
    name: "artlumen",
    description: "idk",

    async run(message, args, client) {
        const artlumen = new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor("RANDOM")
                .setTitle("Elite 0")
                .setImage('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Aceship/Arknight-Images/main/characters/char_4042_lumen_1.png')
                .setTimestamp()
message.channel.send({ embeds: [artlumen] });
    }
});
```

The error

```
TypeError [COLOR_CONVERT]: Unable to convert color to a number.
    at Function.resolveColor (D:\0san-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\Util.js:487:41)
    at MessageEmbed.setColor (D:\0san-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:402:23)
    at Command.run (D:\0san-bot\src\cmd\artwindflit.js:14:3)
    at Client.<anonymous> (D:\0san-bot\src\index.js:57:10)
    at Client.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (D:\0san-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:26:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (D:\0san-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (D:\0san-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:351:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (D:\0san-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (D:\0san-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'COLOR_CONVERT'
}
```

I also tried to use it with a randomizer function, didn't work also

```
const Command = require("../structures/Command.js");
const config = require("../data/config.json");
const {MessageEmbed} = require('discord.js')

module.exports = new Command({
    name: "artlumen",
    description: "idk",

    async run(message, args, client) {
        const artlumen = new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor(ranc())
                .setTitle("Elite 0")
                .setImage('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Aceship/Arknight-Images/main/characters/char_4042_lumen_1.png')
                .setTimestamp()
message.channel.send({ embeds: [artlumen] });
    }
});


function ranc() {
    var col = ["#000000", "#1ABC9C", "#11806A", "#57F287", "#1F8B4C", "#3498DB", "#206694", "#9B59B6", "#71368A", "#E91E63", "#AD1457", "#F1C40F", "#C27C0E", "#E67E22", "#A84300", "#ED4245", "#992D22", "#95A5A6", "#979C9F", "#7F8C8D", "#BCC0C0", "#34495E", "#2C3E50", "#FFFF00"]
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * col.length);
    return(col[rnd])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create function which generate random color and return it or do `.setColor('Random')`

```
function getHex() {
  return '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF).toString(16).padEnd(6, '0');
}
```

and for set color do
`.setColor(getHex())`

Comment: I tried the .setColor('Random') and it didn't work (mentioned in the post). The function is also not the problem, the .setColor() is

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using the EmbedBuilder (https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html). I tested your ranc function and it returns a random color, so the ranc function is prolly not the problem.

```
const embed = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
.setColor("#37AADF");
interaction.reply("Test Embed");
interaction.channel.send({embeds: [embed]});
```

^This code above works fine

So try the EmbedBuilder

Comment: Based on their code, they are using version 13. You are following the guide for version 14, which contains incompatible code. Please visit https://v13.discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview.

Comment: Yea ik but they could simply update the whole project

Comment: If only updating the project is that easy. I have to change the index and a whole bunch of sub-files, which can took a lot of time

Comment: Sorry, @elegance007, but that is not a valid excuse. Version 13 is still a stable version, and if you know someone is using a specific version, it is harmful to provide example answers that break their code.

Comment: Got you guys!

But I think keeping your software always up to date with the newest technologies and versions is very important